# How to design an intermediate representation for language with a nested functions?

Tags: compiler-construction, intermediate-language, compiler-development

I am writing a compiler for language with nested functions.

I decided to use display to access local variables of outer functions from inner ones, I don't know how to represent writing of activation record to display array in intermediate representation, because to do this I need an access to stack pointer register, which is machine-depended.

There is another solution, instead of translate writing of activation record to display into intermediate representation, I can postpone this step to final stage of compilation, which do machine-depended translation.

**So, my question is:**

which solution is better, and if the first one, how to represent writing of activation record to display array in intermediate representation?

Comment: I think you should go with the second one.